# Insert into an Android Room table without triggering an emission?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-database

Is there a way to silently insert/update a Room table that you're observing that will not cause an emission? I have a table where there's one specific case that I don't want to be notified of the change, but still persist it in the same table. I'm not a referring to specific column that I can Ignore since the other cases I DO want an emission...I'm looking for a special way to insert such that my "getAll()" flowable won't be triggered after I perform this one special case insert.

The current solution I was thinking about was having a column(of type bool) that I will "Ignore" and on this special insert set it to true. Upon the next emission(which should be instantaneous and that I don't care about)...check all the bools in that column and if any are set, drop the emission and unset the flag. Feels odd to do this though. I'd rather handle it on the way in than on the way out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. LiveData is observing InvalidationTracker of RoomDatabase
2. InvalidationTracker checks table versions to trigger Observers(LiveData) when RoomDatabase.endTransaction is called.

---bottom line---

A. You can use RoomDatabase.query() to insert/update.

B. If you make two RoomDatabase instance, insert/update through A instance's dao won't trigger B instance's InvalidationTracker.

happy coding